# Upgrading to Heroku:20 stack - SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?

Tags: java, heroku, playback

So I've upgraded from Heroku:18 to Heroku:20 stack (Java backend - Play! 1.4.4 Framework).

Now when I try to deploy new changes to Heroku - the build pipe fails with the following messages:

```
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?

Building Play! application at directory ./

Resolving dependencies: .play/play dependencies ./ --forProd --forceCopy --silent -Duser.home=/tmp/build_ec5a0629 2>&1

File "/tmp/build_ec5a0629/.play/play", line 50

print r"~ _ _ "

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(...)?

Failed to build Play! application

Cleared Play! framework from cache

Push rejected, failed to compile Play! app.

Push failed
```

What is weird here - is that it seems like this is a Python error (print uses parenthesis in python3) - but I'm not using Python even a single bit - anywhere in the project. This is pure Java project.

I found in your docs something about moving from Python 2 to Python 3. Is that something that we should pay attention to? (keep in mind this is pure Java)

What is going on here? Much appreciated on the help